# Google play Something went wrong error on pick a media from gallery

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play, google-play-services

in some devices (especially in **android 14**) when i want to pick a media from gallery using `PickVisualMediaRequest` google play shows **Something went wrong** and i can't do anything.

This is the error:
[click to view error image](https://i.postimg.cc/ZKpqGHKq/74a5b3a6-17f1-4a7a-beda-950036e9eec4.jpg)

Here is my code to pick media:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<PickVisualMediaRequest> pickMedia =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia(), new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
                    if (uri != null) {
                        // my stuff
                    }
                }
            });
```

```
pickMedia.launch(new PickVisualMediaRequest.Builder()
        .setMediaType(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly.INSTANCE)
        .build());
```

***NOTE:*** I use a single signature key in 3 of my apps.

I searched on Google, but I did not find any solution to my problem. also i tested on emulator with android 14 but it worked fine for me.